# IPHONE 4.3.3 ImageIO: <ERROR> JPEGNot a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, wifi, decode

My project:Connected via WIFI, SOCKET transmission.When I receive a picture data，the error-message：`ImageIO: <ERROR> JPEGNot a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9。`

```
-(void)decodeData:(char*)data length:(int)length {
        struct TVDATA *tvData=(struct TVDATA *)data;
        [jpgData appendBytes:(char*)tvData+8 length:length-8];



        if(tvData->m_frag_totle-1==tvData->m_frag_cur) {
            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:jpgData];

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(aa) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:!NO];

            jpgData.length=0;
    }


-(void)aa {
    if(imgView.image!=nil){
        [imgView.image release];
    }
    imgView.image=image;

    [scrollView setDisplayImage:image];

    if (videoflag==1) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(writeVideo) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:!NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a hex editor tell you the data looks like? `0xFF 0xD9` is `EOI`, which means `End Of Image`. See [JPEG here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) for info on the header content.

Comment: but it's worked on ios5+,just ios4.3.3